# deserializing Json Object to C#

Tags: c#, json, api, parsing

Trying to deserialize json but as it has dynamic key value , unable to get the the data in the testTimedict object

JSON:

```
{ 
  "results": {  
    "timesheets": {
      "123456": { 
        "id": 123456,
        "user_id": 36036,
        "jobcode_id": 374398,
        ..
      },
      "635241": {
        "id": 635241,
        "user_id": 36036,
        "jobcode_id": 0,
        ..
      },
      ..   
    }
  }
}
```

C#:

```
public class testroot
{
    private testresults _results;

    [DataMember(Name = "results")]
    public testresults Results {get; set;}
}

[DataContract()]
public class testresults
{
    private testTimedict _timesheet;

    [DataMember(Name = "timesheets")]
    public testTimedict timesheetList {get; set;}
}

[DataContract(Name = "timesheets")]
public class testTimedict
{
    private Dictionary<string, TimeSheets> _timesheet;

    [DataMember()]
    public Dictionary<string, TimeSheets> timesheetList {get; set;}
}

public class TimeSheets
{

    private int _id;
    private int _user_id;
    private int _jobcode_id;
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int ID {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "user_id")]
    public int user_id {
        get { return _user_id; }
        set { _user_id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "jobcode_id")]
    public int jobcode_id {
        get { return _jobcode_id; }
        set { _jobcode_id = value; }
    }
}
```

I am deserializing the string into dictionary but the deserializer returns nothing for the inner most child object i.e "123456"{}

Comment: Where is code for `TimeSheets` class?

Comment: Added Timesheets class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use your classes but please consider better naming for them

```
[DataContract]
public class testroot
{
    private testTimedict _results;

    [DataMember(Name = "results")]
    public testTimedict Results { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class testTimedict
{
    private Dictionary<string, TimeSheets> _timesheet;

    [DataMember(Name = "timesheets")]
    public Dictionary<string, TimeSheets> timesheetList { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TimeSheets
{

    private int _id;
    private int _user_id;
    private int _jobcode_id;
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "user_id")]
    public int user_id
    {
        get { return _user_id; }
        set { _user_id = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "jobcode_id")]
    public int jobcode_id
    {
        get { return _jobcode_id; }
        set { _jobcode_id = value; }
    }
}
```

and you can deserialize with Json.Net - `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testroot>(test);`

Answer (score 0):

Your "dynamic keys" for the timesheets are the same as the `id` properties inside your timesheet objects, so why not get rid of the duplication and make `timesheets` an array?  Like so:

```
{ 
    "results": {  
        "timesheets": [ { 
            "id": 123456,
            "user_id": 36036,
            "jobcode_id": 374398
        }, {
            "id": 635241,
            "user_id": 36036,
            "jobcode_id": 0
        }]  
    }
}
```

That cleans up your c# model considerably:

```
public Results results { get; set; }

public class Timesheet
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public int jobcode_id { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
    public List<Timesheet> timesheets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: how do I convert the Jobject to Jrray?

Comment: Ah, assuming you cannot change your json structure, pretty sure you'd use `JObject.Parse(yourJson.ToString())["results"]["timesheets"].Properties()`. Then you'd loop over those.